# How to remove Bootstrap 5 popover line between arrow and body

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-popover

Does anybody know how to remove the line between the arrow and the body for Bootstrap 5 popovers?  I've tried a hundred things and nothing seems to work. See the image below for what I mean.

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/ajster/4tyw0xn5/7/

```js
var popoverTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]'))
var popoverList = popoverTriggerList.map(function(popoverTriggerEl) {
  return new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl)
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<a href="#" class="ms-5" style="font-size: .85rem; text-decoration: none; color: black;" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-trigger="focus" data-bs-html="true" data-bs-content="This is an example popover.  I don't want to see the line between the arrow and the content box for a clean look.">[Click for Popover example]</a>
```

Comment: Can you share a minimal example on codepen or https://jsfiddle.net/ so that we can replicate?

Comment: @mandy8055 added jsfiddle example and code.

Comment: in the jsfiddle code there is no line.. on your screenshot, it appears as something is adding border to the popover element, or moving the arrow.. try debugging, for example, remove all css styles but BS and then keep adding until it appears

Comment: @traynor, I most definitely do see a line.  See updated screenshot.  I have noticed that I don't see it on my iPad unless I really zoom in.

Comment: nope, can't reproduce, looks fine in latest FF and chrome.. can you try different machines/environments.. It seems that arrow is shifted for 1px away from popover body, so it doesn't cover the border.. I managed to reproduce it only if I reduce arrow position by 1px in `left: calc(-1 * (var(--bs-popover-arrow-height)) - var(--bs-popover-border-width));`... no idea..